# Update items to shopping cart(package-->darryldecode) Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart, laravel-5.7

**My blade file--->**

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'/cart/update', 'method'=>'POST']) !!}
<div class="color-quality">
     <div class="color-quality-right">
     <input type="number" name="qty" value="{{ $cartProduct->quantity }}" min="1">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $cartProduct->id }}">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update" class="item_add hvr-outline-out button2">
     {{-- <button type="submit" name="submit" value="update" class="item_add hvr-outline-out button2">Update</button> --}}
     </div>
     </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**route file-->**

```
Route::post('/cart/update', 'CartController@updateCart');
```

**controller file**

```
public function updateCart(Request $request){
    $qty= $request->qty;
    $id = $request->id;

    /*echo $qty;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $id;*/
   Cart::update($id, $qty);
   return redirect('/cart/show');
```

}

when i'm echo the file and hit UPDATE btn then i get result both of this id & qty number... **return**, on the other hand, get some error...
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

C:\xampp\htdocs\larashop\vendor\darryldecode\cart\src\Darryldecode\Cart\Cart.php
     * update a cart
     *
     * @param $id
     * @param $data
     *
     * the $data will be an associative array, you don't need to pass all the data, only the key value
     * of the item you want to update on it
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update($id, $data)
    {
        if($this->fireEvent('updating', $data) === false) {
            return false;
        }

```
    $cart = $this->getContent();

    $item = $cart->pull($id);

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // if the key is currently "quantity" we will need to check if an arithmetic
        // symbol is present so we can decide if the update of quantity is being added
        // or being reduced.
        if ($key == 'quantity') {
            // we will check if quantity value provided is array,
            // if it is, we will need to check if a key "relative" is set
            // and we will evaluate its value if true or false,
            // this tells us how to treat the quantity value if it should be updated
            // relatively to its current quantity value or just totally replace the value
            if (is_array($value)) {
                if (isset($value['relative'])) {
                    if ((bool)$value['relative']) {
                        $item = $this->updateQuantityRelative($item, $key, $value['value']);
                    } else {
                        $item = $this->updateQuantityNotRelative($item, $key, $value['value']);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $item = $this->updateQuantityRelative($item, $key, $value);
            }
```

Arguments
"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: Just try to ``dd()`` the ``$data`` and check whats in it..

Comment: same result as before

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach means supplied variable is not an array .. just try to dd the $data..

Comment: sorry i don't get it.... im new here...can you write the code please

Comment: You do this ``dd($data)`` before the ``foreach`` and check what its getting when you update the cart.

Comment: try to do dd in your controller where you passing $data to file. Then it will provide you data your getting inside $dada.

Just Pass 
before passing to file
dd($data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Cart::update($id, ['quantity' => ['relative' => false,
                                   'value' => $qty
                                 ]
            ]);
```